# Как сделать так, что бы цвет нижнего подчёркивания input при клике менялся c середины?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт - https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit/index.html
Вопрос: 
Как сделать так же, что бы при клике на input нижнее граница меняла цвет
именно с середины и в разные стороны?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например через градиент можно сделать...

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

input {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 200%;
  padding: .4em 0;
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#a2f, #a2f), linear-gradient(#ddd, #ddd);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: 0 3px, 100% 3px;
  background-position: center calc(100% - 3px), 0 calc(100% - 3px);
  transition: .5s;
}

input:focus {
  background-size: 100% 3px, 100% 3px;
  background-position: center calc(100% - 3px), 0 calc(100% - 3px);
}

input:not(:focus) {
  transition: unset;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #999;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter here">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)

Comment: Хм, интересное решение, я бы обернул `input` дивом и линию сделал через псевдо-элементы)